# Store grid data in Offline

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, offline-mode

I searched through google for offline data store, but i didn't get. I have one kendo grid i need to store the kendo grid data in offline mode when click the button and perform offline data synchronization. I mean Store grid data in Offline local storage. For this download grid data and store in  Offline local storage. and Sync the grid offline changes. Can any one help this, how to implement or any example.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
    <button type="button" id="btnOfflineMode" >Offline</button>

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
              { field: "Name" },
              { field: "Age" },

            ],
            dataSource: [
              { Name: "John Doe", Age: 33  }
            ],

        }).on('focus', function (e) {
          // some thing
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recently introduced a new DataSource feature, which allows you to work with offline data and sync it when necessary.

```
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/offline
```